# What is the current blocker on the ExtendProgram feature in mainnet?

Tags: mainnet

I noticed that extending program buffers has gotten pretty far towards adoption, but the feature is still not on for mainnet-beta:

```
8Zs9W7D9MpSEtUWSQdGniZk2cNmV22y6FLJwCx53asme | inactive                | NA              | enable bpf upgradeable loader ExtendProgram instruction #25234
```

Why isn't it enabled?
One of the Solana programs that we maintain at work is occasionally forcing us to look for size optimizations.  Its buffer is too small and it seems that part of the dev community is also facing this problem. I was hoping that this feature could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey according to the feature schedule it will be activated in 1.16

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/wiki/Feature-Gate-Activation-Schedule

current cluster version you can find out like this:

```
solana cluster-version -ud -> 1.14.19 
solana cluster-version -um -> 1.14.19
```